# How to set null value selectone menu jsf

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 , I have a field Cumulative indicator which is a select drop down wit Y/N/select, when I update the value to Y/N the edit/update is happening fine, but when I chose select as the drop down value it does not update it to null. I am able to set the value to null from the backend. When I chose select as the drop down value it should update to null instead it shows the previous value(Y/N) that is saved in the database. The below is my code xhtml, java bean and the update query. Please advice why its not updating the value to null value.

I tried putting the drop down value itemValue="#{null}" but that didn't work as mentioned in this post How to save Null value with selectone dropdown

Below is my xhtml:

```
<p:column headerText="Cumulative Indicator"   width="60">
<p:cellEditor>

<f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText value="#
 {AcctRefRecord.cumIndicator}" />
</f:facet>


 <f:facet name="input">
    <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{AcctRefRecord.cumIndicator}"
     label="Cumulative  Indicator">
    <f:selectItem 
    itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem 
    itemValue="Y" />
    <f:selectItem 
    itemValue="N" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>

    </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:dataTable id="dtable" var="AcctRefRecord"value="#         
    {AcctRefMBean.

    AcctRefRecords}" editable="true"
        paginator="true" rows="10"  
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}  
        {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}    
        {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >


      <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#
        {AcctRefMBean.onRowEdit}" update=":dtableform:msgs" resetValues="true"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#
        {AcctRefMBean.onRowCancel}" update=":dtableform:msgs"/>
```

Below is my javaBean:

```
//retrive the record/row of type
AcctRefTo on which edit even occurred
AcctRefTo to = (AcctRefTo) 
event.getObject();    
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) 
facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
String userId = (String) 
session.getAttribute(WebAppConstants.CURRENT_USER_ID);

if (userId == null) {
userId =  WebAppConstants.DEFAULT_CURRENT_USER_ID;
}   
to.setUpdatedByUserID(userId);
updateRecord(to);
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Reference Data Updated for  Account#" 

+ to.getAcctNbr());
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance
().addMessage("null", msg);
}

/**
 * @param to
* updates the given to in DB accordingly 
*/
public void updateRecord(AcctRefTo to) {
jetSessionFacadebean.updateAccntRef(to);
}
```

Below is my updateQuery:

```
<key><value>updateAcctgRef</value></key>
<value>
update acct_ref set                  
cd_val=?, 
dt_eff_end=?, 
ind_bal=?, 
ind_bal_acct_type=?, 
ind_cum=?,
ind_net=?, 
ind_net__bal_type=?, 
ind__rcn=?,
ind_b=?, 
nbr_gl_acct_yeb_offst=?, 
nbr_gl_acct_net_unam_bal=?,
cd_fee_cat_type=?,  
id_lst_updt=?,
```

Comment: Can someone please assist. Really appreciate it

Comment: Can anyone please provide pointers